# migrations are getting created repeatedly

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I have created some models and when I run `python manage.py db migrate` command it creates migrations file, so that is fine.
`python manage.py db upgrade` command also creates table in Database.
If I again run the `python manage.py db migrate` command then it is creating migrations file for those models that I have upgraded recently.
Can you please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem and i've resolved it.

In my case, There is a problem on getting current table names.
(when calling get_table_names function in _autogen_for_tables((alembic/autogenerate/compare.py))

I am using sqlalchemy with the mysql-connector.
mysql-connector return table information as bytearray.
so i've changed temporally the following. (base.py(sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql))

```
@reflection.cache
def get_table_names(self, connection, schema=None, **kw):
    """Return a Unicode SHOW TABLES from a given schema."""
    if schema is not None:
        current_schema = schema
    else:
        current_schema = self.default_schema_name

    charset = self._connection_charset
    if self.server_version_info < (5, 0, 2):
        rp = connection.execute(
            "SHOW TABLES FROM %s"
            % self.identifier_preparer.quote_identifier(current_schema)
        )
        return [
            row[0] for row in self._compat_fetchall(rp, charset=charset)
        ]
    else:
        rp = connection.execute(
            "SHOW FULL TABLES FROM %s"
            % self.identifier_preparer.quote_identifier(current_schema)
        )

        return [
            row[0]
            for row in self._compat_fetchall(rp, charset=charset)
            if row[1]  == "BASE TABLE"
        ]
```

to

```
@reflection.cache
def get_table_names(self, connection, schema=None, **kw):
    """Return a Unicode SHOW TABLES from a given schema."""
    if schema is not None:
        current_schema = schema
    else:
        current_schema = self.default_schema_name

    charset = self._connection_charset
    if self.server_version_info < (5, 0, 2):
        rp = connection.execute(
            "SHOW TABLES FROM %s"
            % self.identifier_preparer.quote_identifier(current_schema)
        )
        return [
            row[0] for row in self._compat_fetchall(rp, charset=charset)
        ]
    else:
        rp = connection.execute(
            "SHOW FULL TABLES FROM %s"
            % self.identifier_preparer.quote_identifier(current_schema)
        )

        return [
            row[0].decode("utf-8")
            for row in self._compat_fetchall(rp, charset=charset)
            if row[1].decode("utf-8")  == "BASE TABLE"
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is to manage.py. If you did it as described on flask-migration site and stored all your models in this file - flask-migration just get these models and generates migrations and will do it always. You wrapped the standard command in your file and this is the problem.

If you want to fix it - store models in another directory (or another file), add them to an app and use command `flask db migrate`. In this case, flask-migration will generate migration for models only at first time, for others, it will detect changes and generate migrations only for changes.

**But be careful, flask-migration don't see all changes. From site:**

> The migration script needs to be reviewed and edited, as Alembic currently does not detect every change you make to your models. In particular, Alembic is currently unable to detect table name changes, column name changes, or anonymously named constraints. A detailed summary of limitations can be found in the Alembic autogenerate documentation.